# Django Channels: Exception inside application: No handler for message type app_consumer.notification_message

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to send a notification to the user using websockets, on a particular event.
I have the following model receiver which triggers a websocket method:

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    if update_fields:
        if 'pan_number_verified' in update_fields and instance.pan_number_verified is True:
            notification = Notification.objects.create(message='Your PAN Number has been verified...Head on to '
                                                               'creating a campaign right away.', user=instance)
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("notification_%s" % instance.id, {
                "type": "app_consumer.notification_message",
                "message": str(notification.id)
            })
```

Here is my app consumer:

```py
class AppConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['user_id']
        self.room_group_name = 'notification_%s' % self.room_name
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'app_consumer.notification_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def notification_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

But I get the following error message:

> Exception inside application: No handler for message type app_consumer.notification_message
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in **call**
>       [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
>       await dispatch(result)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 244, in **call**
>       return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 414, in wait_for
>       return await fut
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
>       result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/db.py", line 14, in thread_handler
>       return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 277, in thread_handler
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 107, in dispatch
>       raise ValueError("No handler for message type %s" % message["type"])
>
> No handler for message type app_consumer.notification_message

Answer (score 1):

You issue here is the name of your `notification_message` handler method.

Channels expects it to be named `app_consumer_notification_message`.

Channels replaces the `.` in message types with `_` when looking for a message handling method.

(the prefix in the message type is not used for routing just the group name)